# Combine 2 physical hard-drive into one

Tags: linux

I have a web server running CentOS. I didn't pay attention when I installed it, but now the system running out disk space. I have to check it everyday to delete some unimportant stuffs to make enough space to the system to work. But I think that the server has two hard drives by running the command: fdisk -l , with outputs:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x345698d9

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          39      307200   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
 /dev/sda2              39         137      786432   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.

Disk /dev/sdb: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4cfa1f2d

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1       30402   244197376   83  Linux
```

I don't really understand the above outputs. I got some questions:

Does the system has 2 HDs? and which one is being used and which one is not?

If the one is not in use, Can I combine it with the main disk to make the system disk space bigger?

For more infomation, when I run the command: df -hT, the output are:

```
Filesystem    Type    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1     ext4    230G  152G   66G  70% /
tmpfs        tmpfs    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1     ext4    291M   33M  244M  12% /boot
```

Please help!

Comment: Voting to close. Professional system administratoin (requirement on this site) and "I did not pay attention when I installed the one server I have" is as incompatible as it gets for me.

Comment: Hi Tom, I posted this question on http://stackoverflow.com/ site but it was on hold due to, according to the on-hold message, professional questions. It gives me the link to here and so I posted it here.

Comment: It is unfortunate that this is the case, but alas, it is off-topic here.  At the very least, a professional needs to be able to understand such data as this, and why this question makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the system has 2 HDs?

Yes you appear to have a 160GB drive and a 250GB drive

> and which one is being used and which one is not?

Both are being used.  the 160GB has a small boot partition(sda1), and a small swap partition(sda2) and a huge amount of free space.  The 250GB drive has the root filesystem (sdb1).

> If the one is not in use, Can I combine it with the main disk to make the system disk space bigger?

You can, but it would take re-installing.  You could also just create another partition and filesystem on that 160GB drive, and mount it somewhere and move some of your data do it.  Without knowing exactly how your data is distributed through your disk I can't make any recommendations about where exactly you would mount it.  Running `du -h /` would give would give you an good idea.

You might for example create a filesystem for `/var/log`.  It should be easy enough to create this partition/filesystem and move content to it without majorly interrupting things.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
As you stated, the sda drive has a lot of free space, so I can create another primary partition, let says Sda3, on it. 
I store all my data on the /home directory (now I know that the home directory is on Sdb1 disk). Instead of creating filesystem on the new partition, Can I mount it with the /home directory so I can enlarge the space for /home ? Is that possible?
Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for LVM. Take a look here:
http://ostechnix.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/linux-basics-lvm-logical-volume-manager-tutorial/

At the moment, partition 1 on your first hard disk /dev/sda seems to be used for the /boot partition while partition 1 on your second hard disk /dev/sdb is used for /.

Comment: LVM would allow him to create a partition to span across multiple drives, but setting this up is non-trivial, would require a backup+format+restore, plus it would be dangerous since you would lose all your data if you lose either drive.  (ps I didn't downvote you).

Answer (score -3):

You currently only have 1 Drive and 2 partitions.

For future expansion, consider using LVM or RAID based setups like X-RAID, RAID0,5,6,10 JBOD, ect... which allows you to clump a bunch of disks as one.

Comment: He has two drives.